# Jquery sortable, over, on side or under

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I use sortable to sort divs.
Is it possible to sort divs left or right, and not just up or down?
I created a fiddle with boxes. I can arrange them over and under eachother but not on the side of echother. Is that possible?

**UPDATE**
Also i'd like to choose, if the block is staying on the side or under/over, for each box!

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3qr8z83v/

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-2 well" id="blocks">
  <div class="block" id="block1">1</div>
  <br>
  <div class="block" id="block2">2</div>
  <br>
  <div class="block" id="block3">3</div>
  <br>
  <div class="block" id="block4">4</div>
  <br>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 well" id="dropzone"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.block {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#blocks').sortable({
  connectWith: '#dropzone',
});
$('#dropzone').sortable({
  connectWith: '#blocks',
});
```

Comment: In your fiddle, the sortable `<br>`s are messing up the layout. As for dragging items along either axis, and based on the comments under the existing answers, you can use the `grid` option, but it will likely be easier to achieve with separate `draggable`/`droppable` widgets rather than a `sortable`. *Beware*: jqueryui's `grid`s don't like bootstrap styling very much

Comment: @blgt Thank you! I guess i must re-think. Maby the jquery plugin "gridster" is more fitting for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery sortable cannot work as a grid. i will have to use droppable for that.

Answer (score 1):

floating left sortable div might work so add the CSS `#blocks>div { float: left; }`

Although you might need to adjust your dropzone.

Comment: floating left, will result in always putting the boxes on side to eachother!? I don't want that. Just sometimes..?

Comment: you can apply css conditionally whenever required.

Answer (score 0):

Something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3qr8z83v/9/)**

```
#dropzone .block
{
    float:left !important;
}

#dropzone
{
    display:flex;
}
```

Comment: Well, i don't like ALL boxes to stay on the side. Just the one i choose. So some box will stay under/over and some on the side!?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `br` tag form your markup and `float: left` to this class `.block {}`
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/3qr8z83v/10/)

Comment: Well, i don't like ALL boxes to stay on the side. Just the one i choose. So some box will stay under/over and some on the side!?